# How do I use jQuery in Rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I tried to use jQuery in a Rails view with `if` but it didn't work well. Any advicse?

This is the view:

```
 jquery when the page ready
 :javascript
  $(document).ready(function{
 $('#msg').hide(); 
  })

 -if !@x || !@p 
  :javascript
   $(document).ready(function{
   $('#msg').show(); 
   })
  %h5.alert.alert-error#msg.put Invalid email or password
```

This is the controller:

```
@x=Profolio.find_by_email(params[:user])
@p=Profolio.find_by_password(params[:userpassword])
```

Comment: It's best if you keep your Javascript in separate files and have them included in rather than code them into the view. Just good practice with "separation of concerns."

Answer (score 1):

For one, it looks like your jQuery is malformed. Your view should look like:

```
:javascript
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $('#msg').show();
});
```

Notice the `()` by `function`.

I am also unsure if you're using HAML or what, but `:javascript` could just be `:script`.

Also, Rails should load jQuery by itself as jQuery is the defacto JavaScript framework of newer versions of Rails.

Comment: Your last remark is wrong, regardless of where the Javascript is, if it's dependent on the document is should wait for the document to load before firing.

Comment: @izuriel Thanks, I removed it.